How to detect cloud in time series Sentinel using ArcGIS Pro and Python
This is my code:
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.raster import ImageryLayer

# Connect to GIS (with authentication)
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "credential.username", "credential.password")

# Access shapefile layer
shapefile_path = r"G:\My Drive\__Second (2nd) Chapter\Sentinel-2 10M Land UseLand Cover\Seram\Seram.shp"
shapefile_layer = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(shapefile_path, "pulau_layer")

# Access Sentinel-2 imagery layer
sentinel_layer_url = "https://sentinel.imagery1.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Sentinel2L2A/ImageServer"
sentinel_layer = ImageryLayer(sentinel_layer_url, gis=gis)

# Time period for querying
start_date = "2015-06-01"
end_date = "2024-12-31"

# Function to convert date to required format
def format_date(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

# Loop through each feature in the shapefile
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile_layer, ['Site', 'x', 'y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        island_name = row[0]
        x_coord = row[1]
        y_coord = row[2]

    # Ensure coordinates are valid
    if x_coord is not None and y_coord is not None:
        point = {
            "x": x_coord,
            "y": y_coord,
            "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326}
        }

        print(f"Geometry for {island_name}: {point}")

        try:
            where_clause = f"acquisitionDate >= '{format_date(start_date)}' AND acquisitionDate <= '{format_date(end_date)}' AND CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE <= 5"
            geometry_filter = {
                "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
                "geometry": point,
                "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects"
            }
            
            # Print debugging information
            print(f"Query where clause: {where_clause}")
            print(f"Geometry filter: {geometry_filter}")

            query_result = sentinel_layer.query(
                where=where_clause,
                geometry_filter=geometry_filter,
                out_fields="acquisitionDate"
            )

            if query_result and 'features' in query_result:
                for feature in query_result['features']:
                    acquisition_date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(feature['attributes']['acquisitionDate'] / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    print(f"No cloud available {island_name} on date {acquisition_date}")
            else:
                print(f"No imagery with no cloud {island_name}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error querying imagery for {island_name}: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"invalid coordinate {island_name}")

And I keep encountering this error:

Geometri untuk Benggoi-PC01: {'x': 130.18422, 'y': -3.03432296,
'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}} Query where clause:
acquisitionDate >= '2015-06-01T00:00:00' AND acquisitionDate <=
'2024-12-31T00:00:00' AND CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE <= 5 Geometry
filter: {'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPoint', 'geometry': {'x':
130.18422, 'y': -3.03432296, 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}, 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects'} Error querying imagery for
Benggoi-PC01: Failed to execute query. (Error Code: 400) Geometri
untuk Benggoi-PC02: {'x': 130.185537, 'y': -3.03312703,
'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}} Query where clause:
acquisitionDate >= '2015-06-01T00:00:00' AND acquisitionDate <=
'2024-12-31T00:00:00' AND CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE <= 5 Geometry
filter: {'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPoint', 'geometry': {'x':
130.185537, 'y': -3.03312703, 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}, 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects'} Error querying imagery for
Benggoi-PC02: Failed to execute query. (Error Code: 400) Geometri
untuk Benggoi-PC03: {'x': 130.187244, 'y': -3.032492017,
'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}} Query where clause:
acquisitionDate >= '2015-06-01T00:00:00' AND acquisitionDate <=
'2024-12-31T00:00:00' AND CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE <= 5 Geometry
filter: {'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPoint', 'geometry': {'x':
130.187244, 'y': -3.032492017, 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}, 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects'} Error querying imagery for
Benggoi-PC03: Failed to execute query. (Error Code: 400) Geometri
untuk Benggoi-PC04: {'x': 130.185172, 'y': -3.042376041,
'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}} Query where clause:
acquisitionDate >= '2015-06-01T00:00:00' AND acquisitionDate <=
'2024-12-31T00:00:00' AND CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE <= 5 Geometry
filter: {'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPoint', 'geometry': {'x':
130.185172, 'y': -3.042376041, 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}, 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects'} Error querying imagery for
Benggoi-PC04: Failed to execute query. (Error Code: 400)


There are several problems with the where clause you are using. Reviewing the ArcGIS Rest service directory for Sentinel 2, there is no CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE its cloudcover. Also the way you query the acquisition date was incorrect. Here is some minimal code to show the correct syntax to the query.
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.raster import ImageryLayer
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "X", "Y")
sentinel_layer_url = "https://sentinel.imagery1.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Sentinel2L2A/ImageServer"
sentinel_layer = ImageryLayer(sentinel_layer_url, gis=gis)
start_date = "2015-06-01"
end_date = "2024-12-31"
point = {"x": 130.18422, "y": -3.03432296, "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326}}  
where_clause =  f"(acquisitiondate >= timestamp '{start_date}  0:0:0' AND acquisitiondate <= timestamp '{end_date}  0:0:0') AND cloudcover <= 5"
geometry_filter = {"geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint", "geometry": point, "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects"}
query_result = sentinel_layer.query(where=where_clause, geometry_filter=geometry_filter, out_fields="acquisitiondate")
print(query_result)

